# Improve sed modification between two patterns

Tags: shell, design-patterns, sed, replace

I have this text file:

```
    cat MyFile.xml | grep IndiceKK

      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
...
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22.589">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22.42">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22.47">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
...
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22.47">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22.03">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
```

I want to keep all the text, but just replace "22.xx" by "22":

```
Expected:
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
...
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
      <Ref IndiceKK="22">
```

With `sed -i -e '/IndiceKK/ s/22.[^ ]*/22/g' MyFile.xml`, I can have `<Ref IndiceKK="22`, but I lost the `">` at the end.
So, my trick to save `">` is to add these characters by hand: `sed -i -e '/IndiceKK/ s/22.[^ ]*/22\">/g' MyFile.xml`. It's ok, in my case, but not scalable, for exemple if there is other text after in the line...

Please, do you have a proposal? Thank you in advance

Comment: sed and regular expressions is the wrong tool for working with xml. Probably trivial to do with xmlstarlet

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed -i -e '/IndiceKK/s/22\.[0-9]*/22/' MyFile.xml`

- Match period with `\.` because `.` matches any char
- Match numerals `[0-9]` not non-space `[^ ]`
- don't use `g` for glob match... it's not needed